# How do you add a partial in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I having trouble to add a partial view to display data over and over again

Comment: which version of MVC.net are you using? I mean - there's a difference between @Html.RenderPartial(...) and @Html.Action(...), including parameters and what happens behind the scene,

Answer (score 0):

You use the `Html.RenderPartial` helper to render partial views.

```
<div class="your-wrapper-div">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_YourPartialView"); }
</div>
```

You can also pass a ViewModel to the partial view as the second parameter of the `RenderPartial` helper method.